# Is it possible to subscribe to a specific user's answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I appreciate the ability to subscribe to tags that are of interest to me, and I would similarly like the ability to subscribe to answers from a specific user. Without naming names, I have noticed that there is a particular user whose answers are always well-thought-out and I'd love an easy way to follow them.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56861/how-to-subscribe-only-to-the-questions-of-a-specific-users-feed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just subscribe to the RSS feed in your preferred RSS reader? Lookup the info page of an user; at the bottom, you will see a link `user feed`. You'll get his/her answers and comments.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that was there!

Comment: As an active RSS user, this would work fine for me, although in general it may be something a lot of people don't use.