# How to save favorite users?

Tags: support, users, bookmarks

How can I save my favorite users in the profile? Why would it be possible to mark "favorite" questions but not users?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/980/is-there-something-like-follow-this-question.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to [subscribe to a specific user's answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/937/930).

Otherwise, I believe the response is no: [Is there a way to add a user as favorite at StackOverFlow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94033/150510)